# Joining to dataframe throws warning

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm learning Pandas and I want to get a column from a dataframe and add it to another dataset.

It is easier for me if I explain it with a SQL statement:

```
Select i.item_category_id from items i, transactions t
where t.year = 2014 and i.item_id = t.item_id
```

I have two dataframes: `Transactions` and `Items`. `Transactions` have a column `item_id` that it is foreign key to `Items`, and I want to add the column `Items.item_category_id` to the dataframe `Transactions`, using for that the column `Transactions.item_id`.

From `Transactions`, I only want 2014's summer months:
summer = transactions[(transactions.year == 2014) &
((transactions.month == 6) | (transactions.month == 7) | (transactions.month == 8))]

This is the `summer` head:

[image]

And this the `Items` head:

[image]

Finally, this is the dataframe that I want to get:

[image]

I have found that I can do it this way:

```
summer["item_category_id"] = summer.item_id.apply(lambda item: items.loc[item, 'item_category_id'])
```

But I don't understand what I'm doing and I get the following warning:

```
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead
```

So I have decided to do it by myself:

```
summer["item_category_id"] = items[(items.item_id == summer["item_id"])].item_category_id
```

But it doesn't work:

```
ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects
```

How can I do the join without any errors or warnings?

Comment: Rather than SQL, can you please show your input and expected output (preferably as text)? Code walks, data talks.

Answer (score 0):

The `.join` would be your good friend here. Do give the following a try:

```
items.join(summer, on="item_id")
```

This would perform a left join on default, which works in this case as items:transactions share a 1:M relationship.